# ¿Como puedo restar N cantidad de numeros y que la resta sea correcta en PYTHON?

Tags: python

Estoy aprendiendo python y estoy haciendo el "proyecto básico inicial", que es una calculadora. Lo que hago es preguntar al usuario la cantidad de números que desea restar (ya que quiero practicar "for" y funciones) pero no tengo idea de como hacer que reste varios numeros, dejenme explicar con parte de mi código.

```
def resta():
    preg1=int(input("Escribe la cantidad de numeros a restar: "))

    tot_resta=0
    for i in range(preg1):
        resta_numeros=float(input("Escribe el numero a restar: ")) 

        tot_resta=tot_resta-resta_numero
        print(tot_resta)
```

Como pueden ver, inicializo una variable en 0, pero cuando por ejemplo, el primer numero a restar es 100, entonces tot_resta=0-100=-100.
Si cambio el orden a tot_resta= resta_numero-tot_resta entonces sería tot_resta=100-0 pero en el siguiente ciclo me saldría un número negativo.
¿Como puedo arreglarlo?
Una de mis "soluciones" fue con la función abs(), pero quisiera poder restar incluso numeros negativos.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que puedes hacer es inicializar la variable `tot_resta` con `None` o con `0` y adentro del `for` asignarle el primer valor en caso de que sea igual al valor de inicialización, de lo contrario hacer la resta.

Ejemplo con el valor inicial `None`:

```
def resta():
    preg1=int(input("Escribe la cantidad de numeros a restar: "))

    tot_resta=None
    for i in range(preg1):
        resta_numeros=float(input("Escribe el numero a restar: "))
        
        if tot_resta is None:
            tot_resta = resta_numeros
        else:
            tot_resta=tot_resta-resta_numeros
        print(tot_resta)
resta()
```

Por cierto, la línea `tot_resta = tor_resta - resta_numeros` podría ser cambiada por

```
tot_resta -= resta_numeros
```

Esto se llama [`Operadores de asignación`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/operadores-basicos-en-python-con-ejemplos/)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias.